# HP ProBook 450 G3 freeze on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, hp

Hi I have **HP ProBook 450 G3** with ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed.

Unfortunately it freezes randomly all the time. Seems like problems with graphic card because often just before freeze sth weird happens with the screen (colors/shapes changes).

Is there any extra software which could I install or perform some checks which give me more details about the reason of fails?

//------------- Edit ---------------

Hmmm because of curiosity I have lowered linux to 15.10 but still same problems. In syslog I see sth like this:

```
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689810] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 1080 at /build/linux-qcqUxa/linux-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:3404 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x1de/0x1f0 [i915]()
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689816] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689821] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 hp_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl snd_hda_codec_hdmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp arc4 coretemp snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_pcm iwlmvm snd_seq_midi mac80211 snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd iwlwifi cfg80211 snd_seq_device joydev input_leds snd_timer serio_raw snd soundcore shpchp mei_me mei soc_button_array hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev tpm_infineon acpi_pad hp_wireless mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit r8169 drm_kms_helper mii ahci drm libahci wmi video
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689959] CPU: 3 PID: 1080 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.2.0-42-generic #49-Ubuntu
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689964] Hardware name: HP HP ProBook 450 G3/8101, BIOS N78 Ver. 01.10 04/10/2016
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689971]  0000000000000286 00000000237e1db6 ffff88040ac9b518 ffffffff817f318e
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689984]  ffff88040ac9b570 ffffffffc02016e8 ffff88040ac9b558 ffffffff8107cb86
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.689995]  ffff88040ac9b620 ffff88040ac9b6c4 ffff88040f899000 ffff88040f898000
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690006] Call Trace:
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690027]  [<ffffffff817f318e>] dump_stack+0x63/0x81
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690044]  [<ffffffff8107cb86>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690058]  [<ffffffff8107cc15>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690138]  [<ffffffffc0140c2e>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x1de/0x1f0 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690223]  [<ffffffffc0140dfb>] skl_update_wm+0x1bb/0x740 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690279]  [<ffffffffc018df1b>] ? gen9_read32+0xfb/0x2e0 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690335]  [<ffffffffc0175a22>] ? i915_get_vblank_timestamp+0x62/0xa0 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690369]  [<ffffffffc014457e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690412]  [<ffffffffc01a8bc9>] intel_finish_crtc_commit+0x169/0x190 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690431]  [<ffffffffc00c7df3>] drm_atomic_helper_commit_planes_on_crtc+0x143/0x260 [drm_kms_helper]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690478]  [<ffffffffc01c20bb>] intel_atomic_commit+0x6b/0x100 [i915]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690512]  [<ffffffffc005ce67>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690525]  [<ffffffffc00c672f>] drm_atomic_helper_disable_plane+0xef/0x130 [drm_kms_helper]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690533]  [<ffffffff81214ee0>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x140/0x140
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690560]  [<ffffffffc004ca5a>] __setplane_internal+0x23a/0x2f0 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690567]  [<ffffffff81214ee0>] ? poll_select_copy_remaining+0x140/0x140
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690592]  [<ffffffffc004cc3b>] drm_mode_cursor_universal+0x12b/0x210 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690601]  [<ffffffff817f7d7f>] ? __ww_mutex_lock+0x5f/0xa0
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690632]  [<ffffffffc004cda1>] drm_mode_cursor_common+0x81/0x180 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690659]  [<ffffffffc0050dc0>] drm_mode_cursor_ioctl+0x50/0x70 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690679]  [<ffffffffc0041525>] drm_ioctl+0x125/0x610 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690703]  [<ffffffffc0050d70>] ? drm_mode_setcrtc+0x500/0x500 [drm]
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690710]  [<ffffffff81214205>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x295/0x480
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690717]  [<ffffffff81089a51>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690723]  [<ffffffff81214469>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690727]  [<ffffffff8108c76e>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690733]  [<ffffffff817fa072>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
Feb 22 09:46:20 ziemowit-hp kernel: [  737.690737] ---[ end trace 98941ec3ed2fec4f ]---
```

Comment: It has a "SkyLake" family CPU. The new kernel in 16.10 has many improvements.

Comment: Did not help :(
Ubuntu 16.10 - 64 bit in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after checking a few versions of Ubuntu I have checked it with Windows 10.

Result is the same so unpredictable fails of system.

Seems that hardware is broken. I need to give it back to seler.

Answer (score 0):

you should read on certification.ubuntu.com to find the most suitable version of ubuntu for your laptop. In your case, i think you should install ubuntu 14.04 LTS for HP probook 450 (my laptop is probook 450 G2)

goodluck!